# this keyword within AJAX request jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On click I change the css of the selected div like this:

```js
$(".like-grid-span").click(function() {

  if ($(this).css('color') == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    $(this).css({
      color: 'blue',
      transition: 'all .45s'
    });
    $('.like-count').html(data);
    $(this).prop('title', 'Rated as Good');
  } else {
    $(this).css({
      color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
      transition: 'all .45s'
    });
    $(this).prop('title', 'Rate as Good');
  }

});
```

I just introduced ajax request within the onclick function and added the rest of the code within the success call back, but my this keyword (that was refering to the current selected div) is not working now, I know it may be refering to ajax function now but **how can I still use this to refer the selected div? Or is there any alternative?**

```
$(".like-grid-span").click(function() {
  var selected_offer_id = $(this).closest("ul.amenities").data('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/apexrealestates/goods/goodmechanism.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      user_id: 1,
      offer_id: selected_offer_id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if ($(this).css('color') == "rgb(0, 0, 0)" && data != false) {
        $(this).css({ // this is the my this keyword I'm talking about
          color: 'blue',
          transition: 'all .45s'
        });
        $('.like-count').html(data);
        $(this).prop('title', 'Rated as Good');
      } else {
        $(this).css({
          color: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
          transition: 'all .45s'
        });
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("phat gea");
    }
  });



});
```

Here is my html:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="listing_tile item col-sm-4">
    <div class="options">
      <a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Login" data-container="body" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login">Login</a>
      <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="./property/detail.php">
        <span class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Take a Look</span>
      </a>
      <img src="img/property2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="favt-grid-div" title="Add to Wishlist">
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>For Sale
      <span>PKR 2500000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h3 class="text-center">
                <a href="#">Apartment in Bahria</a>
                <small><?= getExcerpt('556-Safari villas bahria town Lahore'); ?></small>
            </h3>
      <h4 class="text-center text-danger"><b>Lahore</b></h4>
      <ul class="amenities" data-id="2">
        <li><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> 45 Sq-Ft</li>
        <li title="click to Rate"><span class="like-grid-span"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></span><span class="like-count">26</span> Likes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help would be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: assign this to another variable before calling ajax like `reference = this;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store `this` reference in a variable, then use it in `success` callback method

```
$(".like-grid-span").click(function() {
    var _self = $(this); //Store reference
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            //Use the variable
            _self.css({ });
        }
      });
});
```

Additionally you can use `context`, it sets the value of `this` in the callbacks.

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
});
```

EDIT, Unbind and bind click handler

```
function likeClickHandler() {
    var _self = $(this);

    //Unbind click handler
    _self.off('click')

    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            //Use the variable
            _self.css({
            });

            //Bind Click handler
            _self.on('click', likeClickHandler);
        }
      });
}

$(".like-grid-span").on('click', likeClickHandler);
```

Comment: There is an option `context` for that ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff, Yes, we can use `context` also. I was going to add but you have taken care of that

Comment: I'm just not sure why no one use it... :)

Comment: i've used '_this = $(this);' 

'if (_this.css('color')=="rgb(0, 0, 0)" && data != false){ 
                                    _this.css({
                                    color : 'blue', 
                                    transition :'all .45s'
                                });
                                _this.children('span.like-count').html(data);  
                                _this.prop('title', 'Rate this Offer');'

color is changing perfectly, but last two lines are not working, i don't know why

Comment: `_this.next('span.like-count').html(data);`

Comment: @SubhanAhmed, `like-count` is not child of `_this`, You need to use next like `_this.next('span.like-count').html(data);`

Comment: @Satpal One last thing, as you might have noticed that this is a like system; how can I restrict user to not to click like button mulitple times too fast? I hope I am clear.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed, You can unbind event or set a flag

Comment: i've tried _this.unbind('click'); before ajax request and _this.bind('click'); in success, it unbinds but does not binds the click event back. i've also tried _this.trigger('click'); but still no effect

Answer (score 7):

Pass option `context` of `$.ajax()` method:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign `this` to a variable like

```
$(".like-grid-span").click(function() {...

     var self = this;
```

Then use `self` everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

assign `$(this)` object to javascript  variable.

```
 var thisOBJ;
 $(".like-grid-span").click(function() {
    thisOBJ = $(this);
    // success function 
    success: function(data) {
    if (thisOBJ.css('color') == "rgb(0, 0, 0)" && data != false) {
        thisOBJ.css({ // this is the my this keyword I'm talking about
         color: 'blue',
        transition: 'all .45s'
       });
 });
```